# VS Code doesn't see updated dependency in local repository

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In a Java project I have a dependency on my own library. I have installed this library in the local repository by running `mvn install` in the root of the library's directory.

When I updated the library and re-installed it, VS Code couldn't see a newly-added method (everything compiles fine from the command-line).

I've tried `Java: Force Java Compilation` (full) and that didn't work.

In `pom.xml` I right-clicked on my library and chose *Update Project* and that didn't help either.

If it makes any difference, I am running on WSL2 (Ubuntu-20.04) on Windows 10.

Is there any solution short of restarting VS Code (which is a rather cumbersome workaround)?

Comment: How about deleting the previous one in local repository then reinstalling the updated package?

Comment: Or you can clean java language server workspace from Command Palette then try again.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Cleaning Java Language server workspace did work, though it still feels a little brute-force-ish.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT by itself "deleting the previous one in local repository then reinstalling the updated package" didn't work.

Comment: Glad to clean java language server solves your question, I'll write it as an answer and please have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executing the `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` command from the **Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)** should work.

If you added new dependencies or jars, java language server will build and compile them automatically.

In some rare cases, you may need to execute the above command to let the language server rebuild your dependencies.

Reference: [Library Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_library-configuration)